# mysql list by category 3 tables

Tags: php, sql, list, categories

i use to make a product list from an mysql db.

my tables:

```
klantartikels:  
  klantart_art_nummer  klantart_klant_id 
  29216                1
  15151                1
  18215                2

artikels
  art_naam  art_nummer  art_cat_id
  artnaam1  29216       12
  artnaam2  15151       11
  artnaam3  18215       6

categorie
  cat_id  cat_naam
  12      category1
  11      category2
  6       category3
```

table klantartikles holds the user definend products

when user with id "1" goes to his/her list page, i want to display them like this

```
 
category1
  artnaam1

catgory2
  art_naam2

etc.
```

mayby somthing like this?

```
$subcatsql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM klantartikels AS k
INNER JOIN artikels AS a 
ON a.art_nummer = k.klantart_art_nummer 
WHERE k.klantart_klant_id = '1'     GROUP BY a.art_cat_id")or die(mysql_error());
```

sorry for my bad english

thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Search for how a `join` works

Comment: are you looking for just the SQL query? are you looking for all the MySQL code? if you need all the MySQL code, are you looking for it to be in MySQL PDO, MySQLi?

Comment: i'm still using mysql, and yes all the sql code if possible. i've been searching for a while now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` to do this:

```
SELECT art.*, cat.cat_naam as category_name FROM artikels art JOIN categorie cat ON art.art_cat_id = cat.cat_id JOIN klantartikels kart ON kart.klantart_art_nummer = art.art_nummer WHERE kart.klantart_klant_id = '1'
```

You can access everything from `artikels` table, and from the result, you can access the category name by: `category_name`

**EDIT**

For the additional question, the answer is:

```
// FETCH FROM THE DATABASE

$theArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $category = $row["category_name"];
    $art_naam = $row["art_naam"];

    if(isset($theArray[$category]))
        array_push($theArray[$category], $art_naam);
    else
        $theArray[$category] = array("0" => $art_naam);
}

// PRINT IT

foreach($theArray as $category => $item)
{
    print "<h1>" . $category . "</h1>";
    foreach($item as $name)
    {
        print "<div>" . $name . "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: ok your query works fine but this is selecting all my artikels, i want only the klantartikels to be selected with klant_id '1'  and from those klantartikels i want to jump into 'artikles' to get the cat_id so i have to jump into 'category' to get the cat_naam to display it..

Comment: ok, this will be fine for that: `SELECT art.*, cat.cat_naam as category_name FROM artikels art JOIN categorie cat ON art.art_cat_id = cat.cat_id JOIN klantartikels kart ON kart.klantart_art_nummer = art.art_art_nummer WHERE kart.klantart_klant_id = '1'` something else?

Comment: sorry I mispelled that, so modify `art.art_art_nummer` to `art.art_nummer`

Comment: i've done it .. it works ... just an other question how display them like category1{artnaam, artnaam} category2{artnaam} ?

Comment: using a while or foreach? i'd like to make an accordion with bootstrap

Comment: Yes, you have to use a `while` or `foreach` method to do that. I suggest you to first collect the datas from the `while` method to an `array`, and work with that. For example: `$theArray = array(); array_push($theArray[$result['category']], $result['art_naam']);` then you can work with it in another `foreach ($theArray as $category => $name)`

Comment: whoooh like i said before i'm a semi neewbe in php/sql :p  i do this so far while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   echo 'cat id '.$row['art_cat_id'].'<br> ' ;
   echo 'catnaam '.$row['cat_naam'] . '<br>';
   echo $row['art_naam'] . '<br>'; 
  }

Comment: awsome dude this is freaking amazing ^^ i thank you a lot !! you helped my out of a headache i appreciate you're help very much !